# How to do auto complete for same class

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

The textarea will show when I click add row. The textarea has item in autosuggestion on keyup. My problem is the first one shows autocomplete. anothers are not working

```
<textarea id="name" class="name" name="name"></textarea><ul></ul>
<textarea id="name" class="name" name="name"></textarea><ul></ul>
<textarea id="name" class="name" name="name"></textarea><ul></ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".name").keyup(function(){
    var name = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url:"ajax.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:{name:name},
        success:function(res)
        {
            $(".name + ul").append("<li class=item>"+res+"</li>");
        }
    });
}); 

$("ul").on("click", "li", function(){
    var item = $(this).text();
    $(".name").val(item);
    $("ul li").remove();
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you have same `id` and `name` for all 3 fields?

Comment: field will generate automatically by jquery

Comment: What do you mean by automatically? There has to be a way to give different id names. Please refer to my answer.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/examples/EditableInvoice/    I'm using this.. when click add row the row will created. here how can I change ID and Name foreach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that does not need any `id` associated with the text areas.

```
<textarea class="name" name="name1"></textarea><ul></ul>
<textarea class="name" name="name2"></textarea><ul></ul>
<textarea class="name" name="name3"></textarea><ul></ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".name").keyup(function(){
        var field = $(this);
        var name = field.val();
        $.ajax({
            url:"ajax.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:{name:name},
            success:function(res)
            {
                field.next("ul").append("<li class=item>" + res + "</li>");
            }
        });
    });

    $("ul").on("click", "li", function(){
        var li = $(this);
        var item = li.text();
        li.parent('ul').empty().prev('.name').val(item);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: When adding a new row its not working.. help me.. i'm using this for add row  
css-tricks.com/examples/EditableInvoice

Comment: @ManiamuthaKrish you will need to post the code you are using for the add a new row by editing your question or opening a new one

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var name = $(this).val();
var data = name + "&Sessid=" + Math.random();
$.ajax({
    url:"ajax.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:data,
    success:function(res)
    {
        $(".name + ul").append("<li class=item>"+res+"</li>");
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

First of all, change `id` and `name` fields for your `textarea`. It's not good idea to give same `id` name to your elements.

```
<textarea id="name1" class="name" name="name1"></textarea><ul></ul>
<textarea id="name2" class="name" name="name2"></textarea><ul></ul>
<textarea id="name3" class="name" name="name3"></textarea><ul></ul>
```

Now, get id name by this:

```
var which_id = $(this).attr('id');
```

And use `which_id` variable to your ajax response.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"ajax.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:{name:name},
    success:function(res)
    {
        $("#"+which_id+" + ul").append("<li class=item>"+res+"</li>");
    }
});
```